# Flash photo galleries without xml configuration files

Tags: flash, photo-gallery

I saw many examples in jquery compenents which takes image urls from HTML DOM. But flash photo galleries always need xml configuration files as i have seen till now. I need flash compenents which doesn't need any configuration settings from server. If it is possible to do that flash can get image urls from DOM or even by javascript. Is there such as flash photo gallery compenents ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing gallery components, but you best be would be to find one that uses flashvars to configure ([Using FlashVars to pass variables to a SWF](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html)).